# How to make clouds look more realistic

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing

How can I make clouds look more realistic using the cloud gen add on. They always look so fake and round when i do them. Here is a picture of what i mean.

Comment: Sorry the picture didnt upload. Here is a link to the picture. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3K91vxB9L_tY1dwVkJVTnhIemc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please use the edit link under your post to add additional information, and use the tools provided on this site to upload  images. Don't use Google drive, if the link gets deleted then your question will no longer make sense

Comment: Try not to use such vague open terms such as realistic, be as specific as possible, do you want fluffy clouds, stratus type clouds etc? That way your question won't be seen as overly broad, what is your end goal, any reference images? How do you want your clouds to look exactly? *Always be as specific as possible*. Closing until tidied up.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the cloud generator, I think the problem you're having is with the type of cloud you selected. If you started over with the clouds and picked a different type (one which isn't so puffy), then maybe it would look nicer. Please keep in mind I am very new to blender so this is just an idea.

Comment: Even still. It always takes the exact form of he object i created it with.

Comment: Maybe you could make the object itself look irregular using the displace modifier. Then the clouds wouldn't be so boxy and would retain a convincing shape.